# LowercaseQueryStrings Don't work in net5?

Tags: c#, asp.net5

I have a web api in MVC net core to which I pass encrypted parameters which arrive in my api converted to lowercase (which should not happen since the original encrypted value has uppercase and lowercase letters).

Configure the ConfigureServices method of the startup class by setting the following values (but the problem persists)

```
 services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseQueryStrings = false);
 services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = false);
```

This is what I have in my startup class.

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        try
        {

            var iMvc = services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                //options.Filters.Add(new SessionExpireAttribute());
                options.EnableEndpointRouting = true;
            }).AddPluggins(searchPatternList).AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            }).AddFluentValidation();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "session___";
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Configuration["Session:Duration"] == null ? 30 : Convert.ToDouble(Configuration["Session:Duration"]));
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddResponseCaching();
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseQueryStrings = false);
            services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { logger.Error(ex); }


    }
```

What could be happening? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routeoptions.lowercasequerystrings?view=aspnetcore-5.0) `RouteOptions.LowercaseQueryStrings` isn't used unless `RouteOptions.LowercaseUrls` is `true`, which makes me think that maybe you should try

```
services.AddRouting(options => {
    options.LowercaseQueryStrings = false;
    options.LowercaseUrls = false;
});
```

(setting the routing options in just one call to the `AddRouting` extension method rather than two consecutive calls. I think the second one might be overwriting the first one but I'm not sure)

If that doesn't work, I would recommend having a look at `SetCompatibilityVersion` extension method and see if changing the compatibility options fixes it. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I also tried to do this with the same result.